# Details about ping google - xml format, best practices etc

Tags: ping, google, xml, format

Just found http://blogsearch.google.com/ping and I can't find any information about the xml file format.
Is there better way to ping the google bot and can you share sample xml code to show me the exact format that must be send?
Thanks.

Comment: Which xml format? atom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain which xml format you are asking for, but if it's the atom.xml wikipedia is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29